# how does count(1) work with two tables in sql

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables customer and sales.

customer:

```
custid  custname  loc
1001    aaa        a
1002    bbb        b
1003    ccc        c
```

sales:

```
salesid  salesname  saleloc
1001      ddd       d
1002      eee       e
```

I query

```
select count(1) from customer, sales
```

and i get the count result as 6

1. Can anybody explain the logic behind it?
2. Also what kind of join is used if any?
3. if sales has a 3rd column then the count result becomes 9. how does that happen then?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are doing a CROSS JOIN, a cartesian product of the rows since you have no join criteria. Essentially you are getting a row from the LEFT for every row on the RIGHT - `3 * 2 = 6`... `3 * 3 = 9`. The 1 in `count (1)` is insignificant - it will just count the number of rows (1 is just an expression - you might as well use *)

Comment: You mention adding a "third column" on sales? The sales table already has three columns. Did you mean "third row"? Also, you might be able to help yourself explain this if you do a `SELECT *...` instead of `SELECT COUNT(1)...`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @subee . . . You should avoid using `,` in `from` clauses.  If you wrote this using `cross join` (which is equivalent), then answer to your question would be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

It becomes a CROSS JOIN as the tables are not joined with key columns. So number of rows of customer * number of rows of sales (3*2) becomes 6 rows in total and the count function returns that as the result

Answer (score 1):

It is just CARTESIAN PRODUCT.

Each row of the customer table is joined with each row of sales table.

For example,

**1001 aaa a** with **1001 ddd d**, **1002 eee e**  --> when fetching one row from customer tables links with all the rows in the sales table.

So the result comes as 3 * 2 = 6(3 rows in customer table, 2 rows in sales table), Similarly for 3 * 3 = 9.(3 rows in each table)

This is the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

1) 6 is the result of the cartesian product 3 x 2

2) No join is used for 1): it is a cartesian product;

3) 9 is the result of the cartesian product 3 x 3